# battery and cpu usage in 16.04

Tags: battery, overheating

I own an HP Envy AMD A10 notebook, and my problem surfaces only when I'm working on battery.

Basically the fan goes up to maximum rpm, CPU usage builds up, a completely inexplicable overheating appears from nowhere, and in no time I'm facing shutdown due to overheating. I've got this situation every time I'm conected to wifi and using firefox, in other circumstances it may take a little longer but usually the result is the same no matter what specific applications in use.

Furthermore, battery in general, only lasts up to one hour, when in similar conditions using windows8, lasts up to 4:30 hours.

As previously said, none of this happens when connected to power line.

Comment: Run `top` command to find out which app is taking CPU.